# The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I'm trying to save and show image from mongodb database. I save it in database formatted in base-64 String. 
for example this is one of those images:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/+EN/kV4aWYAAE1NACoAAAAIAAgBMgACAAAAFAAAAG4BOwACAAAACwAAAIJHRgADAAAAAQAFAABHSQADA......
```

This is findImage service which changes string format of image to an array of bytes:

```
 public byte[] findImage(String id)
    {
        String str = chRepository.findImage(id);
        byte[] b = str.getBytes();
        return b;
    }
```

and this is findImage in controller class:

```
   @GetMapping("/findImage/{id}")
    public byte[] findImage(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] bb = IOUtils.toByteArray(new ByteArrayInputStream(chService.findImage(id)));
        return bb;
    }
```

I make a url to show images in my script file:

```
<script>
        function makeURL(val, row) {

            if (val){
                return '<a target="_blank" href=  "'  +window.location.href+  'ch/findImage/' + val + '">image</a>';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

but when calling a url like this one:

```
http://localhost:8080/ch/findImage/5
```

it gives the error: the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Note: I guess there is a problem with service findImage function where it changes base-64 String to an array of byte[], but I don't know how to change it to a correct format.

Comment: Show us the whole jsp tag

Comment: say your image is going to be `png` image, then either do `setContentType("img/png");` or do something like  `response.setHeader("content-type", "img/png");` .

Comment: it is just a button which onclick functions is set on makeURL @BasilBattikhi

Comment: okay ? where do you want to add the image ?

Comment: I just want to see image in a new tab when i click the button @BasilBattikhi

Comment: if do you have a console error from browser please post it

Comment: where should I do that? @SJayesh

Comment: when I click on the button a new tab opens which is black with just a sentence on it "the image .. cannot be displayed because it contains errors." but there is no error found in console. @BasilBattikhi

Comment: @user5621266, add it in controller's function where you are returning the image. also add a parameter of HttpServletResponse to the same function to do same.

Comment: @SJayesh but when I check the response in console the response header's content type is image/jpeg.

Comment: @user5621266, if content-type and content-length are showing valid values then the problem might be in how you are fetching from repository.

Comment: I guess the problem is in the service where i change base64 String to an array of byte. but I can't not solve that. @SJayesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling only `getBytes()` on the string but there are two points you have to regard.

1. The string has a special syntax for inlineing image data inside a HTML page. The first part contains the MIME type and `;base64` indicating that the following part after the comma is Base64 encoded.
2. `getBytes()` gives you the byte representation of the string as is. This is not what you want. Because Base64 is a special encoding, you have to treat it specially. You can use the standard class [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) for this.

Example:

```
/**
 * Decodes the Base64 part to bytes.
 * 
 * @param img An inline data encoded in Base64 like <code>"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg..."</code>.
 * 
 * @return Decoded data part
 */
public static byte[] parseImageString(String img) {
  // Avoid a NPE
  if(img == null) {
    return null;
  }

  // Use only the part after the comma
  final int pos = img.indexOf(',');
  if(pos >= 0) {
    final String base64Part = img.substring(pos + 1);
    final Base64.Decoder base64Decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    return base64Decoder.decode(base64Part);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't that something of low security if we send and array of byte to browser instead of a base64 string?

Comment: Base64 doesn't raise the security level. This is not encryption. It is only an alternative representation of the same byte block. If you want only dedicated users be able to view this image you should use HTTPS and a login mechanism with sessions. Then in your servlet handling the image request you can send an error for users not allowed to view this image.

Comment: If it doen't raise security why do we use it?

Comment: Base64 is an encoding to represent binary data with printable characters. So it can be included in text based protocols or embed it inside a HTML page. It's like hexadecimal but with 64 digits instead of 16.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these in your controller:

```
public void findImage(@PathVariable String id,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage myIMG = ImageIO.read(<inputStreamHere>)
    //you'll have to create inputstream for ur image
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", out);
    out.close();
}
```

Or you may do like this:

```
@GetMapping("/findImage/{id}")
public byte[] findImage(@PathVariable String id,
                           HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();   
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   try {
        byte[] b;
        ImageIO.write(<bufferedImageHere>, "png", Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("data:image/png;base64,").append(os);
        b = String.valueOf(sb).getBytes();
        out.write(b);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Exception(ioe);
    }
}
```